# Windows 8.1 will not boot after upgrading from Windows 8 on my PC

Tags: boot, windows-8.1

The PC is a HP EliteBook 8730w laptop. I had no issues with Windows 8 or the Windows 8.1 preview. But after running the Windows 8.1 Update from the store my computer will not boot unless In insert my recovery USB drive and try to repair. The repair fails.

However after I power of the PC and remove the USB drive, the PC will boot correctly once. I would leave the PC on but it shuts it self off at night. And yes I have checked my power profile, it is set to never.

The only thing I have found online is a possibly corrupt video driver. I uninstalled the video driver reboot and it did not fix the issue.

Comment: looks like something wrong happened during install, backup your data and do a fresh install

Comment: Have you tried to boot without install a video driver?  The Windows 8.1 video driver model changed, so Windows 8.0 drivers, do not work with Windows 8.1

Comment: boot from the recovery DVD, enter the repair options, select command prompt and rebuild the BCDstore: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Same issue - resolved by updating BIOS, SSD Driver.

i7, SSD Drive, performed a 8.0 to 8.1 preview - all was fine. Later did 8.1 preview to 8.1 PRO via download from Store.

Performed Windows Update on 8.1, not sure when the boot-up issue was introduced.

Could only boot from Windows 8 DVD, choosing "Repair" and then chose  "Continue to start 8.1"

Once back in service, a power-down, would result in the same issue. I then updated BIO's and SSD Driver (HP) - issue seems resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Try to start booting your PC 3 times then shutting it immediately;

The fourth time Windows repair options should appear and you should be able to revert the update.

After going back to windows 8, try updating all your drivers and your BIOS before trying to update again